# How to solve this issue without having to upgrade to JPA 2.1?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Our application was made using Spring and Hibernate, uses the JPA 2.1 standard and runs on Weblogic 10.3.5.

However, due to restrictions on the client side, we've been forced to downgrade to JPA 2.0. Now it throws errors like `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey` when we try to deploy on Weblogic.

Is it possible to solve this issue by modifying our code, so that we don't have to upgrade to JPA 2.1?  If so, how?

Also, I cannot find the `foreignKey` method in `JoinColumn` (that's an annotation).  Please can someone enlighten me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Downgrade the hibernate version.

Comment: are JPA versions mapped to hibernate versions ? if I am not wrong

Comment: Yes... So depending on the hibernate version there is a minimal JPA version.

Comment: right now we're using hibernate 4.3.3
if I downgrade to a JPA 2 version, my code won't build. it throws errors for 2 missing classes that are present in JPA 2.1 but absent in 2.0
so the error in question is due to compile time and run-time mismatch ?

Comment: Now you are confusing, your post is about deployment not compilation., so which is it.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify
1) our project uses hibernate 4.3.3 (which supports JPA 2.1). 
if I try to build my project using hibernate 4.2.21 (JPA 2.0), I see 2 classes missing (classes present in JPA 2.1 but absent in 2.0) , ok?

2) *However*, if I build using hibernate 4.3.33 itself, but set path to *hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final* in commEnv.cmd file of weblogic server, (basically meaning I am asking weblogic to use jpa 2.0 jar) , then I get the error in question. So is my error due to mismatch in jpa-hibernate jar used during compile time and that used during deployment ?

Comment: No hibernate 4.3 is JPA 2.1 onlu not 2.0 so what you try to achieve won't work. Hibernate 4.3 requires Jpa 2.1 not 2.0.

Comment: we have to use hibernate - 4.2.21 now ! because we have to downgrade to JPA 2.0 . I have some questions in near future . It would be so nice of you if you could reply . Thanks !

Comment: so after downgrading to hibernate 4.2.21 , 2 classes are missing :
javax.persistence.ParameterMode
javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery

and one method
method createStoredProcedureQuery() of javax.persitence.EntityManager

how to substitute them with something in hibernate 4.2.21 (JPA 2)

Comment: Writing native queries.

Comment: How can I know which JPA version my weblogic server is using ??

Comment: How can I know which JPA version my weblogic server is using ??
I am using weblogic 10.3.5
also I commented out the code where error was happening due to missing classes in hibernate-4.2.21 . Maven clean installed the project without any issue but now on deployment , it is giving me that same old error

`javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()Ljavax/persistence/SharedCacheMode; `


I was told by my teamleader that WLS 10.3.5 uses JPA 2.0 by default. our app used JPA 2.1 , thats why we had to downgrade to 2.0 but even now its not working

Comment: Why downgrade. Why not simply include the JPA version in your application (the war/ear) and make sure web logic prefers application classes over its own classes.One thing is that JPA 2.1 needs Java7 if I recall correctly.

Comment: We have tried that . it would work that way ! but there are heavy restrictions on clients server . they won't let us edit commEnv.sh file to accomodate our app. They're already running apps , so won't take that risk. they're a financial business, so risk is even greater from their POV

Comment: please, why am I getting that getSharedCacheMode() error ? is there any workaround it that doesn't involve editing server's files ?

Comment: Why would you need to modify the shell script? It is merely a deployment descriptor in your own application. That way you tell web logic to use your classes over the server ones... You don't need to modify any environment or script for that.

Comment: we modify shell script to tell their Weblogic server to use hibernate 2.1 jar (which is what our app uses) for our app, and not hibernate 2.0 jar (which is what weblogic 10.3.5) uses by default since it comes shipped with that hibernate version. 
above was told to me by my teamleader.

Comment: Can you please tell me how it can be done and what all files need to be edited ?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP571 and check the [`prefer-web-inf-classes`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP600) that is the one you want. Basically add a `weblogic.xml` next to your `web.xml` and add the tags you want as needed.

Comment: It is in weblogic.xml. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#WLPRG286

Comment: thanks , will try now and let you guys know. 
till now, what we're doing is we specify (using PRE_CLASSPATH) in commEnv.sh file that "hey weblogic, please don't use your version of JPA (2.0), please use ours (2.1)." The issue was, the client already has his financial apps running on the same server and wouldn't let us tweak with the commEnv.sh 
So I am assuming `prefer-web-inf-classes` would have the same effect as what we did successfully so far (albeit without client approval) ??

Comment: after turning `prefer-web-inf-classes` to true in weblogic.xml, 
it now gives me following error during deployment  
  
*Neither <prefer-application-packages> nor <prefer-application-resources> can be specified when <prefer-web-inf-classes> is turned on in weblogic.xml*  

following line in weblogic.xml  
   <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>   


to give precedence to our hibernate jars (2.1) over servers default (2.0). So do I remove those package-name tags now ?  
Please help a newbie

Comment: Please anyone still there ?? :(

Comment: If any question requires > 18 comments to get anywhere it means that the question is badly defined and should be reworded/rewritten. Questions should focus on the specific problem, not require comment after comment of clarification